# CSS display on mobile and desktop layout

Tags: html, css

I had a hard time to fix it. Maybe I am just very noob on css. 
Basically, I want the icon to visible only in Mobile version of the site.

in above 767px I put this code to make i hidden. 
`.neighbourhood-img img {display:none;}`

My question is, how can I make it visible in below 767px width..

Thanks!

Comment: We need a bit more context to help you out here.

Answer (score 3):

hey check out this css

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .neighbourhood-img img {display:none;}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {

        .neighbourhood-img img {display:block;}

}
```

Comment: I think the second `media querie` is not necessary;  The `display:none` style only appear when the specified condition is met. Aren't you agree?

Answer (score 2):

What you need is called `media queries`. Try with:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .neighbourhood-img img {display:none;}
}
```

It will be hidden when the width of the screen is at least `768px`

You can read more about `media queries` here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Answer (score 1):

You can use media queries available in CSS to define the styles which meet certain conditions, in you case the condition will be screen width.

Answer (score 0):

Use Css Class:

```
.neighbourhood-img img 
{
display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you're asking.
If you only want it to visible on mobile version then you could do the following:

Make a new **CSS rule**:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .m-show {
        display: block !important;
        max-height: none !important;
        overflow: visible !important;
    }
}
```

Then wrap your icon in a div tag as below, with the styling to hide it (but make its class the m-show class):

```
<div style="display: none; max-height: 0; overflow: hidden" class="m-show">
Your hidden content here...
</div>
```

This will hide it if it isn't in that max width of 767, otherwise it will show it. Hope this makes sense. I would also suggest making that inline styling in the div tag a separate CSS class (just because I don't like inline styling).

Comment: @tomloprod Do you mind me asking why not? -- Edit: I also see the upvoted answer makes more sense